# std::regex fails to match char

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to get a regex to match a char containing a space `' '`.
When compiled with g++ (MinGW 8.1.0 on Windows) it reliably fails to match.
When compiled with [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) it reliably matches

Why would the behaviour differ between these two? What would be the best way to get my regex to match properly without using a std::string (which does match correctly)

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() {
    char a = ' ';
    std::string b = " ";
    cout << std::regex_match(b, std::regex("\\s+")) << \n; // always writes 1
    cout << std::regex_match(&a, std::regex("\\s+")) << \n; // writes 1 in onlinegdb, 0 with MinGW
}
```

Comment: I smell undefined behavior here. You're passing the address of a single `char` and calling it a c-string. What happens when `regex_match` tries to find the length of your "c-string" and starts incrementing that pointer looking for a null character?

Comment: If you have `'\0'` following your char in memory by accident it works. Try `*(&a + 1) = 0;` just for fun

Comment: I see, seems like I misunderstood the docs and assumed that if it asked for a charT* a char* was OK. I think I'll just convert it to a string and use that. Thanks a lot!